# Netcool/OMNIbus SQL procedure not running\doing nothing

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, tivoli

So i have a tool that call procedure.
Tool looks like that:

```
call Attach_test('select TTID from alerts.status where Class in (73000,8891) and to_int(TTID) > 0 and ServerSerial in ($selected_rows.Serial)',[ $selected_rows.Serial ]); flush iduc;
```

it should get TTID (that field have only one of many selected alarms ) and array of server serials of selected alarms. 
Then all this data is transfered to SQL procedure that looks like:

```
declare
tempservser integer; k integer;
begin
for k = 1 to array_len(serserial) do
    begin
        set tempservser = serserial[k];
        update alerts.status set ParentTT = parentttid, TTFlag = 2 where ServerSerial = tempservser and TTID = '' ; 
    end;
end
```

Parameters:

- in **parentttid** Char(11)
- in **serserial** array of Integer

---

And here comes the trouble - procedure do nothing. There is no errors or something but there is no update on selected alarms.

I want it to work like this - you select many alarms with only one that have TTID, run this tool that set ParentTT = TTID on every other of selected alarms. 
OS ver. 8.1

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

### Tool

```
call AttachSelectedToTTID([ $selected_rows.Serial ],[ $selected_rows.ParentTT ]);
flush iduc;
```

### Procedure

```
declare
tempservser integer; k integer;n integer;partt char(15);
begin
for n = 1 to array_len(ttid) do 
    begin
        if (ttid[n] != '' ) then
            set partt = ttid[n];
        end if;
    end;
for k = 1 to array_len(serserial) do
    begin
        set tempservser = serserial[k];
        update alerts.status set ParentTT = partt,TTFlag = 2 where Serial = tempservser and TTID = '';  
    end;
end
```

### Parameters:

- in ttid array of Char(15)
- in serserial array of Integer